# tunnel way between Cloud SQL and GCE wih cloud proxy process on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-sql-proxy

I am wondering tunneling way during commnunication between Cloud SQL and Cloud Sql proxy process.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy

I refer to this URL.
I can see "he proxy uses a secure tunnel to communicate with its companion process running on the server."

Could you know what way of tunnel it use during connection ?
ssh tunnel or PPTP, IPSec , L2TP ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Cloud SQL Proxy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) it uses a [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) encrypted tunnel as explained below:

1. Secure connections: The proxy automatically encrypts traffic to and from the database using TLS 1.2 with a 128-bit AES cipher; SSL certificates are used to verify client and server identities.
2. Easier connection management: The proxy handles authentication with Cloud SQL, removing the need to provide static IP addresses.